# Need to change a jsp file to vm file in jira

Tags: java, jsp, virtual-machine, jira

I have a JSP file with tags as follows

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ww" uri="webwork" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="ui" uri="webwork" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="aui" uri="webwork" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="page" uri="sitemesh-page" %>
<%@ page import="com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager" %>
<%@ page import="com.atlassian.jira.web.action.util.FieldsResourceIncluder" %>
<%@ page import="com.atlassian.plugin.webresource.WebResourceManager" %>
```

I need to convert this file to vm file .how to include these tags in vm file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't import java tag libraries in a vm file. You can't import the classes too and you don't need it actually, you can make them available in your vm context following the instructions in the [velocity development guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.4/developer-guide.html#The%20Context)

Comment: The velocity context should have most of what you want. If you're creating a custom field type you can add other objects to the velocity context.